# Rename first 20 characters of every filename in a file

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I am trying to write a script in powershell to remove the first 20 characters of every MP3 filename in a folder, I have created a file 'test.ps' and inserted the powershell code below into it,

```
gci *.mp3 | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(20) }
```

When I run this file in powershell.exe nothing happens,

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may get you started. (There are probably much more concise ways, but this works and is readable when you need to maintain it later. :-) )

I created a folder `C:\TempFiles`, and created the following files in that folder:

```
TestFile1.txt
TestFile2.txt
TestFile3.txt
TestFile4.txt
```

(I created them the old-fashioned way, I'm afraid. <g>. I used

```
for /l %i in (1,1,4) do echo "Testing" > TestFile%i.txt
```

from an actual command prompt.)

I then opened `PowerShell ISE` from the start menu, and ran this script. It creates an array (`$files`), containing only the names of the files, and processes each of them:

```
cd \TempFiles
$files = gci -name *.txt
foreach ($file in $files) {
  $thename = $file.substring(4);
  rename-item -path c:\TempFiles\$file -newname $thename
}
```

This left the folder containing:

```
File1.Txt
File2.Txt
File3.Txt
File4.Txt
File5.Txt
```

In order to run a script from the command line, you need to change some default Windows security settings. You can find out about them by using `PowerShell ISE`'s help file (from the menu) and searching for `about_scripts` or by executing `help about_scripts` from the `ISE` prompt. See the sub-section `How To Run A Script` in the help file (it's much easier to read).

Comment: Thanks Ken, I've got this working now ! I am running scripts in the powershell ISE rather than creating a ps1 file. Although I have just encountered another problem, it only works on files that don't have blank spaces in their names. for example the file "song.mp3" will work but the filename "this song.mp3" throws out an error, saying the file could not be found. Is there a work around with this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know, I'm afraid. I just added files to the folder named "New Test 21.txt" through "New Test 25.txt" and ran the same script in PS ISE, and it worked fine here, leaving files "Test 21.txt" through "Test 25.txt".

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually works. Two things...

1. Rename the file to `test.ps1`.
2. Run it in the folder you have your MP3 files in. Since you didn't provided a path to `Get-ChildItem` it will run in the current directory.

I tested your line by making a bunch of mp3 files like this -

```
1..30 | % { new-item -itemtype file -Name (
    $_.ToString().PadLeft(30, 'A') + ".mp3" )}
```

Comment: I don't understand. I have saved it to a ps1 file and loaded it within powershell by changing to the directory the ps1 file is located and inserting the command ".\test.ps1" to execute my code. I get no errors when I do this but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a more "safer" way (you'll get an error if the file name is shorter than the length in question, you are also targeting the file extension as a part of the total characters). Check if the base name of each file is greater than 21 characters (if you remove the first 20 it can be still have a name with one character long). It can fail if the directory contains a file with same name after you removed the first 20, you can develop it further on your own):

```
gci *.mp3 | foreach{

    if($_.BaseName.Length -ge 21)
    {
        $ext = $_.Extension
        $BaseName = $_.BaseName.Substring(20)
        Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$BaseName$ext"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// delete (replace with empty char) first 20 charters in all filename witch is started with "dbo."
// powershell

```
Get-ChildItem C:\my_dir\dbo -Recurse -Force -Filter dbo.* | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.name).Substring(20) }
```